# Drop duplicates in pandas time series dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have time series data in a data frame that looks like this:

```
Index Time Value_A Value_B
0     1    A       A
1     2    A       A
2     2    B       A
3     3    A       A
4     5    A       A
```

I want to drop duplicate in the Value_A and Value_B columns such that duplicates are only dropped until a different pattern is encountered.  The result for this sample data should be:

```
Index Time Value_A Value_B
0     1    A       A
2     2    B       A
3     3    A       A
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The usual trick to detect contiguous groups is to compare something with a shifted version of itself.  For example:

```
In [137]: cols = ["Value_A", "Value_B"]

In [138]: df[~(df[cols] == df[cols].shift()).all(axis=1)]
Out[138]: 
       Time Value_A Value_B
Index                      
0         1       A       A
2         2       B       A
3         3       A       A
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed!